# Finding values in elements of a list greater than X

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of elements called "find_gaps", below are the first 3 elements of the list:

```
$`2014-11-01 00:33:18`
 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 118  

$`2014-11-01 01:35:58`   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 116   

$`2014-11-01 02:34:28` 1  25  25
```

I want to find values greater than or equal to 24 in each element, and have the output as a data frame where each column contains rows equal to the number of values greater than 24 for each list element. For example, the first element in "find_gaps" would correspond to a data frame column having only one row (with value 118). I am sure there is a way to do this, I have used the code below but I only get the position/index of the value in each list element greater than 24, and not the value itself:

```
  greater_than_24<-lapply(find_gaps,function(x)which(x>=24))
```

Comment: I gave a shot at a solution - but can you be explicit about what you want your output to look like if that isn't satisfactory?

Comment: could you clarify your expected output some more?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please use `dput` function to copy your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
greater_than_24<-unlist(lapply(find_gaps,function(x) length(which(x>=24))))

> as.data.frame(t(greater_than_24))

  V1 V2 V3
1  1  1  2
```

Alternatively - this will pull off the values greater than 24 in each element of the list:

```
greater_than_24<-lapply(find_gaps,function(x) x[which(x>=24)])

> as.data.frame(t(greater_than_24))
   V1  V2     V3
1 118 116 25, 25
```

Comment: The alternative (second solution) is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an accepted answer, and the OP has described that he expects the output *in wide form*.

Nevertheless, I would like to propose a different approach which returns the result *in long form* (including the names of the list elements). I hope the OP finds this alternative representation of the result useful.

```
library(data.table)
data.table(find_gaps, name = names(find_gaps))[
  , .(value = unlist(find_gaps)), by = name][value > 24]
```

> ```
>                   name value
> 1: 2014-11-01 00:33:18   118
> 2: 2014-11-01 01:35:58   116
> 3: 2014-11-01 02:34:28    25
> 4: 2014-11-01 02:34:28    25
> ```